# AttributeError: OracleDBConnector instance has no attribute 'cache_connection' in QGIS DBManager

Tags: qgis, oracle-dbms

I have a connection with an Oracle Database but when I try to make a query  using DB Manager of QGIS it appears "Not Connected" and I get a Python error:

```
1   Traceback (most recent call last):
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 426, in rowCount
                self._refreshIndex(parent, True)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 477, in _refreshIndex
                if item.populate():
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_model.py", line 158, in populate
                if not connection.connect():
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\oracle\plugin.py", line 126, in connect
                return self.connectToUri(uri)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\oracle\plugin.py", line 73, in connectToUri
                self.db = self.databasesFactory(self, uri)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\oracle\plugin.py", line 79, in databasesFactory
                return ORDatabase(connection, uri)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\oracle\plugin.py", line 161, in __init__
                Database.__init__(self, connection, uri)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\plugin.py", line 211, in __init__
                self.connector = self.connectorsFactory(uri)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\oracle\plugin.py", line 164, in connectorsFactory
                return OracleDBConnector(uri, self.connName)
              File "C:/OSGEO4~1/apps/qgis-ltr/./python/plugins\db_manager\db_plugins\oracle\connector.py", line 112, in __init__
                if self.cache_connection:
            AttributeError: OracleDBConnector instance has no attribute 'cache_connection'
```

It is strange because I can add the layers using QGIS Browser, so I guess it is connected.

Anyone knows how to solve it?

Comment: I know it doesn't help, but it looks like a bug/unimplemented feature in the DB Manager.

Comment: Does seem like a bug looking at the QGIS Github project.  If the `__init__` says the `data_sources_cache.db` is not a file, the `self.cache_connection` is never assigned. Some other exception or adding an else setting `self.cache_connection = False` would work. Another thought would be to check your settings directory path as that is where the cache db is supposed to be located.

Comment: Does anyone came up with a solution to this problem?